# HTTP server on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, http, apple-watch, watchos

Currently I am working on ability to start HTTP Server for my independent apple watch app. I did not find such option for now, is there a way at all to start Http server on Apple Watch not iPhone?
Thank you for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to send HTTP requests and start a server somewhere else, or do you want the server itself to run from your apple watch?

Comment: My purpose here is to start Server itself on apple watch (run on apple watch) which is difficult or even impossible to do